# TryValidate and manually set values in cotroller (ASP MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation

I have a "New user" form both for admins and for regular users. Both form use the `RegisterModel`

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The difference is that on my front end "New user" page I want users to provide their own password. But in back end, I want the system to generate the password.

Since I use the same `RegisterModel` for both forms, I get a validateion error in the back end saying `Password is required.`.

I thought, I could solve this by adding this to my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(RegisterModel model)
    {
        model.Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(6, 1);

        if (TryValidateModel(model))
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

But I still get the error message `Password is required.`. Why is this the issue when I do call `TryValidate` in my controller?

What would be best practice for this issue, create a separate `RegisterModelBackEnd` or are there any other solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating model manually, you do not need to use it as parameter in Action. Also, use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470377.aspx) that lets you specify only the properties on which binding will occur.

```
protected internal bool TryUpdateModel<TModel>(
    TModel model,
    string[] includeProperties
)
where TModel : class
```

---

So, the working code will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New()
{
    RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
    model.Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(6, 1);

    if (TryValidateModel(model, new string[] {"Name", "Email"}))
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

You can make this even simpler, using [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New([Bind(Exlude="Password")]RegisterModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       model.Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(6, 1);
       // Do Stuff
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And finally ***simplest and the best way***

> Define separate view models

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I tried the `[Bind(Exclude="Password")]` which looked promising, but I still got the error. I guess I have to add a hidden field in the view for the password for it to work. I will go for `Defining separate view models` I was hoping this was the best way, but did not know if it was best practice or not.

Comment: Yes, that is best way and practice. View models should be defined for all the concrete cases separately. There's no point in using same models plus "hacking" approach for different scenarios.